# Meteor Collection Contains Outdated Info

Tags: json, mongodb, collections, meteor

I had code that made a HTTP get call from the server, used EJSON.parse to parse that data from the url (initially in JSON format), and then added info from the parsed data to a Meteor collection. It worked fine, but some time after updating to Meteor 0.6.5, the code stopped working. In my code, I remove all members of the collection on sever startup before making the HTTP call and inserting into the collection. I noticed something weird while looking at things in the console: the collection contains information that is no longer there. I have since removed the code that made the HTTP call and inserting into the collection, yet there are still objects in the collection. In fact, there are objects in the collection that contain information from the url that are from the day before and are no longer at the url. How can this be?

EDIT: Here is some of the code with the HTTP call:

```
Halls = new Meteor.Collection("halls");
```

...

```
if (Meteor.is_server) {
    Meteor.startup(function () {
        Halls.remove({});

        var result = HTTP.call("GET", "http://claremontcollegemenus.appspot.com/json");
        var parsedData = EJSON.parse(result.content);

        for (date in parsedData.dates) {
            if (parsedData.dates[date].date == today) { // Check for today's date
                for (var menu in parsedData.dates[date].menus){
                    Halls.insert({name: parsedData.dates[date].menus[menu].name, meals: parsedData.dates[0].menus[menu].meals, date: parsedData.dates[date].date});
                }   
            }
        }
   });
}
```

In addition, I commented `if (Meteor.is_server) {` (causing an error) and then uncommented it, and now nothing is in the collection.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Can you please post some code?

Comment: Maybe data transfer from another place.

Comment: I just added some code to my post. What does data transfer from another place mean?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any errors about EJSON being undefined? 0.6.5 release made it required to explicitly add all package dependencies.

Try `meteor add ejson` in your project folder and tell us what you get.

Comment: Give more information, as I said before, look for error messages or post minimal code that shows your case.

Comment: I just did the following "experiment": I added `Halls.insert({name: 'hello'});` within `if (Meteor.is_server)`, restarted the server, and then searched `Halls.findOne({name: 'hello'})` within the Javascript console on Chrome, where I was running my app locally. The search returned undefined. I then added `Halls.insert({name: 'hello'});` within `if (Meteor.isClient)` and then searched `Halls.findOne({name: 'hello'})`, which returned an object. I then removed both instances of `Halls.insert({name: 'hello'});` and restarted the server; the object still appears when I search on the console.